# Fetch POST with formData is empty in Express JS route

Tags: node.js, fetch, form-data

I have a form that uses fetch() to AJAX with a route on NodeJS. When the AJAX POST hits the route, req.body shows an empty object {}.

Here's the code:

**// in app.js**

app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

**// in form.js**

```
form.getElementById('form__option').addEventListener('submit', e => {
    e.preventDefault()
    const form = $('form')[0]
    fetch('/polls/create', {
        method: 'POST',
        body: new FormData(form)
    })
})
```

// in appRoute.js

```
exports.createPost = (req, res, next) => {
    console.log('req body', req.body)
    res.send('NOT IMPLEMENTED: pollsController createPost');
}
```

Comment: did you put your app.use(...) before your routes definition ?

Comment: Yes, both app.use execute before app.use(..., router)

Comment: The code seems about right. You should check your request body from the browser, make sure they're correct (you can use Chrome DevTool's "Network" tab). Then try to add an app.use the very beginning of  your routers(middlewares) and check the `req.body` see if its right

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The issue here is that `FormData` will set the content type to be `multipart/form-data`, which Express' `body-parser` doesn't understand.

Note the comment [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/body-parser):

> [body-parser] does not handle multipart bodies, due to their complex and typically large nature. For multipart bodies, you may be interested in the following modules: busboy and connect-busboy; multiparty and connect-multiparty; formidable; multer.

So in other words, you have to user a different module to handle the multipart body that FormData sends. I can recommend `formidable`, in which case you're server code would look something like:

```
const formidable = require('formidable')

exports.createPost = (req, res, next) => {
    var form = new formidable.IncomingForm();
    form.parse(req, (err, fields, files) => {
        console.log(fields)
        res.send('NOT IMPLEMENTED: pollsController createPost');
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, I can confirm that this is the issue. I had EXACTLY the same problem as the OP and could only solve it by using the suggestions from the answer above.